# Instantiate prefabs in 3 different locations randomly

Tags: c#, random, unity-game-engine

I need to spawn a prefab in 3 locations one at a time. it goes like it spawns on spawn location 1, then after a second, spawns to another spawn location either 1 2 or 3 at a random.

I can only instantiate the object by using this code:

```
transform.position = Random.insideUnitCircle * 5;
```

but I need the spawn location to be fixed like (5,0,0) (3,0,0) and (0,0,0).

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to keep a list of positions

```
List<Vector3> positions = {...};

void SelectPosition(){
 //Generate index (a random integer between 0 and 2)
 //Assign to transform.position = positions[index];

}
```

Sorry for the Pseudocode, I am on mobile, will try to expand upon it later.

Comment: i actually read something similar somewhere problem is its in JS and he is using "case" to call the functions. maybe you can enlighten me how this works? thank you so much. im new and learning at the moment

Comment: you could call that function from within Update() with just SelectPosition(), if you need to call it on certain time intervals you can save the last time it was called in a class variable, and check the current time against it (remembering to update the class variable every time you call SelectPosition() )

Comment: so i give up. after some days trying i still cant get it to work. cant seem to understand the list<vector>3. so any help would be appreciated still. :)